# How to find connectors for Densitron TFT displays

Tags: connector, tft, flexible

I'm having a hard time to find information about the connectors for a TFT display I just bought from Densitron. The cable is physically similar to FFC/FPC, but the terminals are not straight, so I can't use normal FFC/FPC connectors.

[image: display terminals]

The measures are in mm, and this particular connector has 39 pos. Does anyone knows if there's a specific name I should search for at Digikey/Avnet/etc.?

Comment: Why don't you ask Densitron?

Comment: @LeonHeller - Although their TFTs are pretty good, they are not the best for support. I had a simple query, which they took an age (over a month IIRC) to reply to. Plus I don't think they will even let you register for support at all unless you give company details.

Comment: I did ask, but no answers until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the connector you need is one like [this](http://uk.farnell.com/kyocera/04-6281-239-202-829/connector-fpc-zif-0-3mm-39way/dp/1558198) or similar. They seem to be quite common now, I suspect if you type in "FFC 39" (or "FFC" and then select results with 39 pins) most of the results will be similar. Here are the [results](http://uk.farnell.com/jsp/search/browse.jsp?N=203755%20110203587&No=0&getResults=true&appliedparametrics=true&locale=en_UK&divisionLocale=en_UK&catalogId=&prevNValues=203755&mm=1002541%7C%7C,&filtersHidden=false&appliedHidden=false&originalQueryURL=/jsp/search/browse.jsp?N=203755&No=0&getResults=true&appliedparametrics=true&locale=en_UK&divisionLocale=en_UK&catalogId=&prevNValues=203755) I got when doing this on Farnell, I only checked the first two but they both had the same pattern (I selected the second as the first is no longer stocked)

If you check near the bottom of the datasheet, it shows a diagram of a typical FPC pattern which would be used with it. This looks like the diagram in your question, you can check the dimensions to make sure.

Comment: The "results" give me an invalid query.

Comment: @Majenko - thanks. Strange it's done that a couple of times for farnell searches. I think it was because I searched for "ffc" first then narrowed the results down (39 pins) I tried this again just now a few times but it didn't fix it. When I did it by going to the FFC/FPC connectors manually and narrowing down it worked (well for me anyway)